# how to execute oracle procedure in ssis sql execute task?

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

I have one sp in oracle with input and output parameters. Under ssis package i have one for each loop passing the input parameter to execute sql task. Under this execute sql task this sp resides. 
Pls help me to how to execute oracle sp under execute sql task in ssis. The output of the sp parameter needs to update an sql table.

[9 input parameter and 10 output para]

sp command using oledb connection: Exec ?= nps_am_etl_pipinfo ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?OUTPUT, ?OUTPUT,?OUTPUT, ?OUTPUT,?OUTPUT, ?OUTPUT,?OUTPUT, ?OUTPUT,?OUTPUT, ?OUTPUT

Error : [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "Select  p.st_cd
,p.lob_cd
,pcv.pol_id
,pcv.pol_tra..." failed with the following error: "The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::Variable" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.
". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: What is the datatype for the variable User::Variable

Comment: Can you also post  what your parameter mapping table and results set tab look like from your SQL Execute task.